# Proper onDestroy() / How to avoid memory leaks

Tags: android, view, memory-leaks, android-activity

I read a number of articles on how to avoid memory-leaks in Android, but i'm still not quite sure if I got it right.

1. My Application consists of a single `Activity`.
2. I don't have any private or static members in that Activity, all code is started from within `onCreate()`.
3. In have some self-contained static classes whose static instances sometimes hold references to a  `Context` or `View`s. In my `onDestroy()` method, I set all of these instances to null.
4. I recycle all of my `Bitmap`s.

**Q1**: Is that enough?

What confuses me is the classic example of a no-go you can find on the net (http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  setContentView(label);
}
```

I thought that, as soon as `onCreate` finishes, `label` goes out of scope and is GCed.

**Q2**: How can this create a memory-leak?

My Activity basically looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Statics */
    AssetUtils.initIndex(this);
    BitmapLoader.startInstance(this);

    /* frame */
    ViewGroup frame = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frame, null);
    this.setContentView(frame);

    /* create controller */
    Controller controller = new Controller(frame, getLayoutInflater());

    /* START */
    controller.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onStop();

    /* Statics */
    AssetUtils.destroyInstance();
    BitmapLoader.destroyInstance();
}
```

Inside `Controller` I occasionally retrieve a `Context` using `View#getContext()` to pass it to manually created `View`s and the like. It's never stored statically somewhere, only in member-variables of classes which all go back to `Controller`.

**Q3**: Is there something I overlooked?

Comment: Q2: Have you observed a memory leak within your Activity?

Comment: Not yet, though i don't know how I would observe one. I haven't got any error-messages and I haven't profiled my application yet. It's landscape-only (customer demand) so it won't be destroyed upon rotation.

Comment: But Q2 refers to this article: http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/ which says 

"This means that views have a reference to the entire activity and therefore to anything your activity is holding onto; usually the entire View hierarchy and all its resources."

But doesn't every View have a reference to a Context?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Q1.  You've taken this out of context (no joke intended :)

If you see the original article, the leak actually occurs in the next fragment of code where the Bitmap field is introduced.  Roman then clearly explains why it leaks.  The code you have shown will NOT leak.

http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Q2.  Use Activity context only where there is no other choice and NEVER allow a reference to it in something with a scope greater than the scope of the Activity it references.  The code you've shown doesn't leak as far as I can see since nothing has a context reference with a scope greater than your Activity.  Do you suspect that it does?

Q3.  When using Bitmaps, static references or not, I am in the habit of unbinding Bitamps from Views in onPause() (remember onDestroy() is not guaranteed but it's kind of irrelevant as if you're being destroyed, your process is killed so GC isn't a concern).  The linked article also explains how to do this.  I have made it a template pattern for any of my Activities handling Bitmaps.

[EDIT]

Sorry, I just checked.  The article does not show how to unbind.  Here's the pattern I use:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
        super.onPause();

        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout));
        System.gc();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout));
        System.gc();
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view)
{
        if (view.getBackground() != null)
        {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
}
```

`mainLayout` is the root view of the Activity layout.

I include onDestroy() since I might manually finish() my Activity.

Note.  Calling system.gc() is a complex subject and you **might** want to omit it.  There are some good discussions on here why it might not be a good thing to do, principally concerned with performance.  However, in my view, when an activity is being destroyed, hinting that now is a good time to perform GC can do no harm.  The inefficiency of calling it unnecessarily will be lost in the overheads of destroying an activity.

Comment: You say the process is killed, but how can there be memory-leaks at all in that case? Is the object-graph preserved somehow? And what's the benefit of unbinding Drawables?

Comment: Of course there are no leaks if your process is killed, which is fine if Android kills your process but not if you destroy by for example an orientation change in which case your activity instance is destroyed but since the bitmap is static, it is not.  The bitmap now has a reference to the (no longer existant) context and all of it's resources preventing the GC from freeing them.  The key here is static so, yes, you only need to do this if you have static references but I use it anyway, since it does no harm and I will never make the mistake.

Comment: will this routine descend through Fragments?

Comment: i see it does !! +1 for aaaawesome routine, thanks a lot for sharing !

Comment: Hi! Your routine has helped me a lot, however I have a problem I don't know how to solve: The routine effectively cleans everything but the adapterView. My problem is precisely, an adapterview I have is leaking, and I don't know how could I force-clean it. What is the usual procedure for this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Unbinding the Drawables is a good solution but System.gc() is an indicator of fundamentally broken code. You don't know what sort of garbage collector you are running under. You don't know what it's going to do. It's not even guaranteed to do anything. The JVM may just entirely ignore your request. The combination of "you don't know what it will do," "you don't know if it will even help," and "you shouldn't need to call it anyway" are why people are so forceful in saying that generally you shouldn't call it.

Comment: @JasjitSinghMarwah I respectfully disagree.  It's a hint to the OS that now may be a good time to collect.  Of course, it might result in nothing but I would argue that the fundamentally broken code is in Android.  Why do apps need to unbind at all given that the references to the drawables are going out of scope?  That you need to do this is inarguable.  Perfectly correct code will fail spectacularly if this is not done.  I also know *exactly* what "sort of garbage collector" I am running under.  It's a recursive mark and sweep strategy employed by the Dalvik VM.

Comment: I have one question: If you hit pause on your device or if you go to do something with another application, then what will happen when you return to the application? You will be capable of restore all the views?

Comment: why does unbinding drawables hang the applicaton when moving to the next activity?? please help

Comment: Please start a question for it!  It is probably something in your code.

Comment: It's absolutely rubbish to unbind views in onPause as you will have to bind them again in onResume

Comment: @user1530779 Fine.  But what if you don't unbind, then following onPause(), for some reason outside your control, the activity is destroyed?  I use onResume much more than I do onCreate which for me, is only used for initial stand up, onPause being for tear-down.

Comment: @Simon There are very rare cases in which activity is destroyed without calling onDestroy but initializing in OnResume you are destroying the whole purpose of OnCreate Tell me something Ok you are unbinding in OnPause if user goes to home button 10 times at a go and resumes your app each time you will end up initializing your views 10 times a suggestion is to override onRetainInstanceState() and unbind there for Scenarios OS kills your activity

Comment: @user1530779 Getting bored already :)  onPause() is the only callback guaranteed to be called except for a catastrophic OS failure, in which case I don't need to care.  You use a pattern that works for you, I'll use a pattern that works for me.  But to call it rubbish shows a remarkably arrogant and ill-thought through attitude to robust application development.  You have also completely missed the fact that I am only unbinding drawables, not destroying my entire view heirarchy. Good bye and good luck with your development.

Comment: But I have simple viewpager which has 5 images (width and height are same as screen width) as items in listview. This is crashing the app in 512 MB phone, when I scroll 4-5 items in the listview . In this case how can I dispose object and free up memory. Because there is no way for pause and destroy.

Comment: thanks for the code! but i can't believe you use brackets on new lines! :$